# Echo once per foreach

Tags: php, arrays, hex

So I have the following code:

```
$colors=$ex->Get_Color("images/avatarimage3.png", $num_results, $reduce_brightness, $reduce_gradients, $delta);
foreach ( $colors as $hex => $count )
{
    if ($hex == 'e6af23' && $count > 0.05) 
    { 
        echo "The image has the correct colour"; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        echo "The image doesn't have the correct colour"; 
    }
}
```

Basically this code at the moment grabs the hex value and percentage of colours than image contains and adds them to an array. The code above looks to see if the hex is a certain value and the percent above 5% and if it is then it displays the success message. This part works exactly as it should do!

Now, what I also want is that if the colour isn't correct, so for all other hex values in the array other than $hex == 'e6af23' I want it to display a failure message but only display it once and not for every time the hex isn't that value.

Basically I need it so that the failure message is only displayed once and not 5 times (the number of hex colours in the image).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a flag to indicate if the message has been outputted or not, and if so then don't output again:

```
$colors=$ex->Get_Color("images/avatarimage3.png", $num_results, $reduce_brightness, $reduce_gradients, $delta);
$error_displayed = false;
foreach ( $colors as $hex => $count ) {
    if ($hex == 'e6af23' && $count > 0.05) {
        echo "The image has the correct colour";
    } else if (!$error_displayed) {
        echo "The image doesn't have the correct colour";
        $error_displayed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Why didn't I think of doing that. Thank you! :) I'll accept your answer when the 10 minute mark has passed :)

Ah wait - If it is a success it also shows the failure message as well once. Is there a way to completely remove this failure message if the color is already a success.

Comment: The reason for this is because it obviously loops through the array and the hex I'm looking for isn't always first so therefore a failure message is display in front of the success message when this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep a list of colors you already echoed.

```
$failed = array();

forech ($colors as $hex) {
    if (!in_array($hex, $failed) && $error) {
        echo 'Failed at hex ' . $hex;
        $failed[] = $hex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using NewFurnitureRay's answer as a guideline I came up with this answer:

```
$colors=$ex->Get_Color("images/avatarimage.png", $num_results, $reduce_brightness, $reduce_gradients, $delta);
$success = true;
foreach ( $colors as $hex => $count ) {
if ($hex !== 'e6af23') {$success = false; }
if ($hex == 'e6af23' && $count > 0.05) {$success = true; break;}
}

if ($success) { echo "Success"; } else { echo "This is a failure"; }
```

Seems to work now as it should only displaying either a success or a failure regardless of the success's position in the array :)